# Android - get imageView XY coordinates

Tags: android

I need to know XY coordinates of an ImageView. This coordinates will be used to position a new ImageView on an RelativeLayout overlay that should have the same position of starting ImageView.

Summerize:
1) ImageView1 = getcoordinates XY
2) button click
3) Overlay RelativeLayout that cover entire window. ImageView1 will be behind this RelativeLayout overlay
4) Create ImageView2 in RelativeLayout overlay that should be positioned exactly on ImageView1

Any help? Thanks

Comment: use `ImageView#getImageMatrix()` to get the `Matrix` that is used for image drawing on the `ImageView`, from the docs: `"This (Matrix) is applied to the view's drawable when it is drawn."`

Comment: This looks like an XY problem. :-D

Comment: Why not just replace ImageView1 with ImageView2?

Answer (score 0):

If your ImageView is in the root hierarchy, you can simply call

```
imageView.getLeft(); // x-coordinate
imageView.getTop(); // y-coordinate
```

However this only works if the ImageView is in the root hierarchy because the return value is relative to its parent.

If the ImageView is nested and not in the root hierarchy, use

> [public void getLocationOnScreen (int[] location)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getLocationOnScreen(int[]))
>
> Computes the coordinates of this view on the screen. The argument must
>   be an array of two integers. After the method returns, the array
>   contains the x and y location in that order.

```
int[] location = new int[2];
imageView.getLocationOnScreen(location);

int x = location[0];
int y = location[1];
```

Comment: I just tried imageView.getLocationOnScreen(location) but when I set these values in new ImageView it doesn' t position correctly. Can u provide an example on how to set these values in new ImageView? thanks

Comment: @AugustoPicciani of course it doesn't position correctly because the ImageView's Matrix "is applied to the view's drawable when it is drawn"

Comment: @AugustoPicciani since you are using a RelativeLayout, setting the view position should not work. what you can do is to use the x and y coordinates and set it as the imageview's left and top margin.